# using From Web Query in a loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to pull data from this website: http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page=1

Each "page" is a table with 21 items. There are 97 pages I would like to pull data from, but I am unable to automate it so that the macro cycles through all 97, and places the results every 21 rows, starting on cell A1. (sequence: a1, a22, a43, ect...)

this what I got, but I dont want to edit the code 97 time to get all the pages. Any idea how I could automate the task?

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page=1", Destination:=Range( _
        "A1"))
        .Name = "filings.html?page=1"**
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
end Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For x = 1 to 97
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page=" & x, Destination:=Range( _
        "A" & (1 + ((x - 1) * 21)))
        .Name = "filings.html?page=" & x
    End With
Next
```

x contains page number and the cell is complicated to make it start at A1 rather than A21.

You could make it `0 to 96` and cell `& (1 + (x + 21))` and the name and query `x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon the 'from Web Query' method and delve into some xmlHTTP. For the following, you will have use the VBE's Tools ► References to add *Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls* and *Microsoft XML 6.0*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mcr_Collect_Filings()
    Dim htmlBDY As HTMLDocument, xmlHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim rw As Long, pg As Long, iTH As Long, iTD As Long, iTR As Long
    Dim eTBL As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    For pg = 1 To 99    '<-set to something reasonable; routine will kick out whehn it cannot find anything more
        xmlHTTP.Open "GET", "http://securities.stanford.edu/filings.html?page=" & pg, False
        xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        xmlHTTP.send

        If xmlHTTP.Status <> "200" Then GoTo bm_CleanUp

        Set htmlBDY = New HTMLDocument
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText

        Set eTBL = htmlBDY.getElementById("records").getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
        If eTBL Is Nothing Then GoTo bm_CleanUp

        'skip the header row if on page 2 and above
        With Sheet1  '<-worksheet codename
            rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For iTR = (1 + (pg = 1)) To (eTBL.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length - 1)
                For iTH = 0 To (eTBL.getElementsByTagName("tr")(iTR).getElementsByTagName("th").Length - 1)
                    .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(iTR, iTH) = _
                      eTBL.getElementsByTagName("tr")(iTR).getElementsByTagName("th")(iTH).innerText
                Next iTH
                For iTD = 0 To (eTBL.getElementsByTagName("tr")(iTR).getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1)
                    .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(iTR, iTD) = _
                      eTBL.getElementsByTagName("tr")(iTR).getElementsByTagName("td")(iTD).innerText
                Next iTD
            Next iTR
        End With
    Next pg

bm_CleanUp:
    Set eTBL = Nothing
    Set htmlBDY = Nothing
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

The XMLHTTP is invisible so you have to know a little about the page and what to expect in the form of HTML code you are going to receive under different circumstances. A browser's *Inspect Element* command take care of that.

This is by far the fastest method in VBA. While you actually have more than 99 rows to retrieve, this went to 99 pages in 56.3 seconds. You might even speed that up a bit by turning off screen updating.

Comment: It seems to loop content at row 3947 so there may only be 197 pages.